# Button shown disabled in IE9 but shown enabled in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

I have a button in a webform which is shown as disabled in IE9 while when the same page is opened in IE10 it is shown as enabled.

What is the reason why this behaviour is observed?

BElow is the part of the aspx page.

```
<div class="controlBox">
              <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" OnClick="btnYes_Click" />
              <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" OnClick="btnNo_Click" />
        </div>
```

And this is how its visibility is controlled

```
document.getElementById("btnNo").style.visibility = "visible";  
document.getElementById("btnNo").disabled=false;
```

Is it got something to do with how disabled property is handled by IE10.

Comment: or better yet a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Can we see what the browser gets? I don't have a copy of ASP.net running at this moment.

Comment: any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: @Jan: No errors in the console. Is it something to do with setting the disabled property.

Comment: Take a look to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't that be

```
document.getElementById("btnNo").disabled=true;
```

Comment: Its just a sample code i added. The disabled property is changed at runtime to false or true. Either way why is there a difference in the behaviour between IE9 and IE10.

Comment: If I remember I'll try it out at home, I've got Win8 there. I only have Win7 and IE9 here at work. Sorry I'm not more useful