# How can I disable the submit button?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code How can I disable the submit button. It doesn't appear to be working for us.I want to be able to have the button disabled when the page is brought up.  Do you have any ideas on how we can fix this?

```
// Script 10.5 - pizza.js
// This script creates a master checkbox.

// Function called when the checkbox's value changes.
// Function toggles all the other checkboxes.
function toggleCheckboxes() {
'use strict';

// Get the master checkbox's value:
var status = document.getElementById('toggle').checked;

// Get all the checkboxes:
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

// Loop through the checkboxes, starting with the second:
for (var i = 1, count = boxes.length; i < count; i++) {

    // Update the checked property:
    boxes[i].checked = status;

} // End of FOR loop.
}
} // End of toggleCheckboxes() function.

function disabled () {
    if ('')
    {document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;}
    else
    {document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;}


// Establish functionality on window load:
window.onload = function() {
'use strict';

// Add an event handler to the master checkbox:
document.getElementById('toggle').onchange = toggleCheckboxes;

document.getElementById('submit').disabled = disabled;

};
```

Here is the html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Operating Systems</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script </script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Script 10.4 - pizza.html -->
<form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">
<fieldset><legend>Create Your Own Pizza</legend>
<div><label>Toppings</label> <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle"        value="toggle"> All/None
<p><input type="checkbox" name="ham" id="ham" value="ham"> Ham
<input type="checkbox" name="mushrooms" id="mushrooms" value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms
<input type="checkbox" name="onions" id="onions" value="onions"> Onions
<input type="checkbox" name="sausage" id="sausage" value="sausage"> Sausage
<input type="checkbox" name="greenPeppers" id="greenPeppers" value="greenPeppers">  Green Peppers </p>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" required> I agree to the terms, whatever they are.
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</fieldset>
<div id="output"></div>
</form>
<script src="js/utilities.js"></script>
<script src="js/pizza.js"></script>
<script src="js/modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: {document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;}
    else
    {document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;}

is what we have been using and its not helping

Comment: As a side note don't rely on javascript to disable a submit button exclusively. Anyone can edit your javascript on their page instance and remove the disabled attribute, or submit the form from a 3rd party website. Make sure you also have server-side security checks setup to prevent things from happening that shouldn't if someone tampers with your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could be improved:

1. You should close all your input tags to avoid any issues rendering the HTML document.
2. The `for-loop` should run until `i < (boxes.length - 1)` to avoid selecting the ToS checkbox. Or you could target *just* the toppings with `querySelectorAll('p input[type="checkbox"]')` and start from `var i = 0`.
3. The closing bracket for `disable()` is between the closing brackets for the `for-loop` and`toggleCheckboxes()`.
4. In `disabled()` `#terms` is selected, you want to check if it is `checked` or not. If it is, enable the submit button (`disabled = false`), else disable it (`disabled = true`).
5. Finally, you'll want to assign `disabled()` to the `#terms`' `onclick` function so it is called every time the checkbox is toggled.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/4Rwfs/1

#### HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create Your Own Pizza</legend>
    <div>
        <label>Toppings</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" value="toggle">All/None</input>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ham" id="ham" value="ham">Ham</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mushrooms" id="mushrooms" value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="onions" id="onions" value="onions">Onions</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sausage" id="sausage" value="sausage">Sausage</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="greenPeppers" id="greenPeppers" value="greenPeppers">Green Peppers</input>
        </p>
    </div>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" required> I agree to the terms, whatever they are.</input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></input>
</fieldset>
<div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
// Script 10.5 - pizza.js
// This script creates a master checkbox.

// Function called when the checkbox's value changes.
// Function toggles all the other checkboxes.
function toggleCheckboxes() {
'use strict';

// Get the master checkbox's value:
var status = document.getElementById('toggle').checked;

// Get all the checkboxes:
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('p input[type="checkbox"]');

// Loop through the checkboxes, starting with the second:
    for (var i = 0, count = boxes.length; i < count; i++) {

        // Update the checked property:
        boxes[i].checked = status;

    } // End of FOR loop.
} // End of toggleCheckboxes() function.

function disabled () {
    if (document.getElementById('terms').checked)
    {document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;}
    else
    {document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;}
}

// Establish functionality on window load:
window.onload = function() {
'use strict';

// Add an event handler to the master checkbox:
document.getElementById('toggle').onchange = toggleCheckboxes;

document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;

document.getElementById('terms').onchange = disabled;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the submit button on page load, try adding this:

```
document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
```

The following line doesn't make sense unless the disabled function returns a boolean:

```
document.getElementById('submit').disabled = disabled;
```

For example, this would work if you wanted the submit button to disable on click.

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = disabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the disable line.

What did you trying to do with `if('') {` ? Also, in your `onload` function, there is a line :

```
'use strict';
```

What are you trying to do again?

See : http://jsfiddle.net/ByKEJ/

Comment: Exactly that is the part that we can not figure out

Comment: so what are you saying we need to fix the if('')?  well to what?

Comment: @BrittanyKaup, Yes. You'd want want to provide it with the condition for when you'd want the submit button to be disabled.

Comment: yes we understand that but we've tried putting everything in there.

Comment: Could you edit your post to show us what you've tried? Also the HTML would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

[How to disable html button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript)

I think this previous solution can help you dynamically disable something

Comment: It would be helpful if what goes in the if was told to us