# Disabling this button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this button `<button id="beg" onclick"disable()">beg</button>`. And function is defined here

```
function disable(time){
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
};
```

Problem is that button doesn't get disabled, I have no idea why.

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript

Comment: That question doesnt answer my question, so it's not duplicate.

Comment: Yes it does. It's the exact same issue that you have.

Comment: I don't see in that question problem with ´this´.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `this` in your function is not a reference to the `button` element. Try this:

```
<button id="beg" onclick="disable(this)">beg</button>
```

```js
function disable(el){
    $(el).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
};
```

Or better yet, separate your HTML and JS completely by hooking up your event in JS:

```
<button id="beg">beg</button>
```

```js
$('#beg').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: That was too fast +1.

Comment: Is missing a =? Like <button id="beg" onclick="disable(this)">beg</button> ?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward ah yes, thanks. Also thanks VisioN for the edit.

Comment: Can you explain me that (el), please?

Comment: @Kyrbi `el` is the variable holding the reference to the element which was clicked on.