# Disabling image buttons after the first click

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, web

I have designed a web page which consists of 12 button of type image.After clicking on each button it retrive a question from database using servlet and display it on the web page.I want to the disable the buttons after they are clicked.I tried using .diabled=true but its not working.And the button are "NOT" in the "FORM".Can anybody help me??I using JSP,Servlet and javascript.

Comment: you want to disable using javascript?

Comment: you have to use session/cookies to store which buttons were clicked, then probably give a css class to the clicked ones and use javascript to block clicking them using preventDefault() or onclick="return false;"

Answer (score 2):

For XHTML `<input type="button" disabled="disabled" />`  is the valid markup.

For HTML5 `<input type="button" disabled />` is used by W3C in their samples.

`disabled` is a Boolean attribute and hence can be assigned `true` or `false`

```
foo.disabled = true;
```

Also in theory you can set `foo.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');` but it can not be trusted for IE.

For more details read this thread [How to disable html button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

use diabled="disabled" instead of disabled=true

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(this.disabled === true){
        return;
    }
    alert('request the data');
    this.disabled = true;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/canvast/F7Gd2/1/