# Make a button unclickable after one click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button that becomes deactivated after the first click; however I have no clue how to do it.
This is what I have now:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="Fuction();" />
```

This button will NOT submit a form. Could someone help me? I'm totally new to this. I've tried following the answer in other threads but got lost.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the preferred way of course, but this will get you the result you are after.

```
function Fuction() {
  document.getElementById('btnSearch').disabled = 'disabled';
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer make an unnecessary DOM look-up, but it works nonetheless.

Comment: The major problem with this is that a user would need to define one function for every button they want to apply it to, which isn't exactly a good idea.

Comment: Of course. That's why I said it's not the preferred way. However it does work and it is very simple. I may be mistaken but I gathered OP was a beginner and beginners need trivial solutions to problems in order to get going.

Comment: It comes down to if you want to teach beginners _a solution_ or if you want to teach them _a good solution_.

Comment: @Meredith IMO, SO isn't a programming language course, and no solution is without a downside. What he should be doing is explaining why exactly this is "not the preferred way"

Comment: @Pavlo I'd be ok with that

Comment: I'd say that most often it's more sensible to teach them a solution they can understand at the level they are at.

Answer (score 5):

Separating javascript from HTML:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!" id="form-button"/>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('form-button').onclick = function () {
    this.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `disabled` attribute in the end of your handler:

```
function Fuction(button) {
    // your code

    button.disabled = true;
}
```

Markup:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="Fuction(this);" />
```

Comment: Not quite. Don't forget that the `this` keyword _doesn't_ refer to the button element. (It applies to the window object when `Function()` is attached in the manner shown in the question)

Comment: Bingo! That's more like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call [`event.preventDefault()`](http://mdn.io/preventDefault) in the functions implicitly added event variable to first stop the propagation. To disable it afterwards just call [`setAttribute("disabled", true);`](http://mdn.io/setAttribute) on the element. Something like

```
function aMeaningfulName(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.setAttribute("disabled", true);

    // your logic here
}
```

Comment: `e.target.setAttribute("disabled", true);` – why not `e.target.disabled = true`?

Comment: @Pavlo For no apparent reason… ;-)