# How can I hide a form after submission with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

So I have these forms:

django template:

```
 {% for F in forms %}
    <input type="text" name="name/>
    <input type="number" name="number/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" [onclick="this.disabled=true,this.form.submit(); ??]> #how can I make this work?
 {%endfor%}
```

What the template code does is render out multiple forms based on the value of forms> I want the user to submit the form and then have the form either disappear(preferable) or at least disabled so that they can resubmit. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you submitting the form via ajax? Because if not, then hiding it would be pointless since the browser will be taking the user to the form submission script anyways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable html button using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript)

Comment: what if it submits to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple forms on the page and want to handle them with JavaScript, I would suggest you to use jQuery. You could make something like:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    // here comes your logic
    // and the next line removes the corresponding form
    $(this).parents('form').remove();
});
```

But as Marc B pointed out, you should submit the form via Ajax. I don't know what do you intend to do with the user input, but if you want to use Ajax then you could make something like:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        // your logic
    });
});
```

Check the official documentation of jQuery for more details and adapt the examples to your needs.

EDIT:

if you want to prevent the form from submitting and refreshing the page, please change it slightly to:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        // your logic
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```