# Disabled button in a loop for single column

Tags: javascript, html, button, getelementbyid, disabled-control

I have 1 row and 3 column. Each column have 3 buttons with different `id`s.

example id:

```
--column 1--       --column 2--       --column 3--
id="1morning"      id="2morning"      id="3morning"
id="1evening"      id="2evening"      id="3evening"
id="1afternoon"    id="2afternoon"    id="3afternoon"
```

*I want to disable button in column 2 with `id="2evening"`

I know how to disable button using javascript but I do not know how to manipulate the javascript so that I can disable the button that I want.

HTML code:

```
<br>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="well.hilang"> 
    <table>
      <tr>
       <?php
       for ($i=1; $i <=3 ; $i++) { 
         ?>
         <td>
           <?php echo $i;?>  
           <div class="form-group">
             <input class="btn btn-l" type="submit" name="submit" id="<?php echo $i;?>morning" ><br>
             <input class="btn btn-l" type="submit" name="submit" id="<?php echo $i;?>evening" ><br>
             <input class="btn btn-l" type="submit" name="submit" id="<?php echo $i;?>afternoon" >
           </div>
         </td>
         <?php }
         ?>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```

JS code:

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i <=3 ; $i++) { ?>
<script>
  document.getElementById("<?php echo $i;?>evening").disabled = true;
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is the Javascript disabled button in all column that have `id="1evening"`, `id="2evening"` and `id="3evening"`. What I want is to disable button with `id="2evening"` only.

Thanks, 
faizal

Comment: `document.getElementById("2evening").disabled = true;`

Comment: if(<?php echo $i;?>evening === "2evening"){
document.getElementById("2evening").disabled = true;
}

Comment: I dont want to set it manually, I want to use loop. Or maybe I can put If statement before the loop this JS loop code?

Comment: the correct answer from @user2181397 thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector isn't correct. In `document.getElementById(<id here>)`, you just need to tell it the element ID that you want to work with. So if you want to disable the `2evening` button, you would do the following:

`document.getElementById("2evening").disabled = true;`

More Information: [How to disable html button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Make function for than then you can use with every event like `onload` or `onclick`

> HTML

```
<body onload="myFunction()" >
    <button id="myBtn" >My Button</button>
    <!--<button id="makesomething" onclick="myFunction()">Click Here to Disable above button</button>-->
</body>
```

> JavaScript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: does not help anything.
anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: this is to clear your fundamentals. this is not ready-made answer.