# Click event not firing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to fire a click event when the page loads but only once on each page load. What is happening is that in localhost it works fine, but when I upload to server it dosen't fire at all.

The idea was to set a counter to 0 when the page loads then inc the counter by 1 to disable further clicks. Obviously, there is an error somewhere but I cannot solve it.

I am using jqwidgets jqxgrid to display the data and getting the class as a variable. I am also using jquery 1.11.1

I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this as I seem to have tried many combinations, but ok on localhost but nothing on server. I am using php v5.3.13 wamp and 5.4 on server. Many thanks

```
var counter = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  var calendaricons = document.getElementsByClassName('jqx-icon-calendar');

  for (var i = 0; i < calendaricons.length; i++) {
    calendaricons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (counter === 0) {
        notif({
          type: "info",
          msg: "Test Message",
          width: 650,
          height: 99,
          multiline: true,
          position: "center",
          fade: true,
          //timeout: 3000,
          autohide: false,
          clickable: true
        });
        counter++;

      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: if you're using jquery as your tag says, you can use `.one('click', '#myId', function() {...})`

Comment: Doesn't declaring the counter inside the load function solve the problem?

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626357/769326

Comment: load the page with your browser console ON & you would see an error if any.

Comment: There are no errors in firebug. All libraries are loaded and error free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, which it seems the case, you can use the `one` function that allows your handler to be runt only once.

Here is your code with the use of the `one` function:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.jqx-icon-calendar').each(function(index, item) {
        $(this).one("click", function() {
            notif({
              type: "info",
              msg: "Test Message",
              width: 650,
              height: 99,
              multiline: true,
              position: "center",
              fade: true,
              //timeout: 3000,
              autohide: false,
              clickable: true
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Love the handle. Problem is that is the page reloads it dosen't fire again. I have to do a force refresh in ff then it will work. Need it to work using regulat page load. Thanks

Comment: So, you can use `$(document).ready`instead of `$(window).load`. I've just "translated" your native code.

Comment: I have put in document ready but still not firing on server although all other js is working fine. Just this one script. Any suggestions as to how to troubleshoot. Thanks

Comment: Can you make a `JSBin` with the code to see wat's happenning ?

Comment: Not sure how tom use but i shall try. Will post back. Thanks

Comment: How do I add a local file to jsbin? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried to create fiddle but it is not working. I tried to include the js for the test message but it fails miserably because of my inexperience and I have probaly missed other code to make the grid. Is there any other ay to do this? Thanks