# How to disable non-input elements with jQuery (or js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable a bunch of elements (divs that have onClick and other custom events) while a request is taking place.

I have tried with:

```
$("selector").children().prop("disabled", true);
```

Also with:

```
$("selector").children().attr("disabled", true);
```

Also with:

```
$("selector").children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Neither of these worked, meaning that, they all kept their functionality even after disabled was applied to them.

To confirm that I am actually able to target all of the desired elements I tested with:

```
$("selector").children().css({backgroundColor: "black"});
```

All elements became black, so the targeting is correct.

I am open to any other suggestions on how to disable elements, basicly these are divs that should not be clickable (there are other events of interest, not just the `click`), for the duration of a request, once a div is clicked, that is why I am trying to temporarily disable them, and re-enable them again, once I receive the response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable HTML button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript)

Comment: @M-Chen-3 it is what I have tried to do, but it doesnt work for me. I don't know how to provide minimal example in this case, as it is all within a large shopify theme. I can see the disabled attribute being applied to the elements (which are divs), but it doesnt take effect.

Comment: @Darkbound That right there is your problem. You need to disable the buttons, not the divs.

Comment: Are you SURE the elements you wish to disable are `<button>`? That attribute/property does not apply on `<div>` or `<li>` element "looking" like buttons...

Comment: @M-Chen-3 okay, but I don't have buttons, I have divs, is it possible to do it with divs? Or do I have to re-do them into buttons?

Comment: What does it even mean to disable a div?

Comment: If using `divs` I'd just add a class of `disabled` with `addClass` and remove with `removeClass` --  You can control your cursor, color etc etc that way with CSS classes, and you'll be able to check the class on the button action IE `click` with `.hasClass("disabled")`

Comment: Since the element are NOT `<button>`.. You could try: `$("selector").children().css({pointerEvents: "none"});`

Comment: And `$("selector").children().css({pointerEvents: "initial"});` to restore...

Comment: Thanks guys, I have corrected my description to specify that these are divs and not button elements, that was my mistake. The css with `pointerEvents` did the trick! Thank you! Someone can add the answer officially, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Darkbound: I would suggest a title change to your question... While I can do it myself (lol), I prefer you do it yourself if you agree on the idea. So the idea is to change `Disable elements with jQuery (or js)` to `How to disable non-input elements?` or something like... ;) That, for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `disabled` property only applies to input elements, such as `<input>` and `<button>` for example. It does not apply to some `<div>` or `<li>` styled to look like a button or input (could be a div content editable).

To disable an element that is not a "real" input element, you can use `$("selector").children().css({pointerEvents: "none"});` which will just prevent ALL events on that element and childs, no matter the event handlers binded.

To restore: `$("selector").children().css({pointerEvents: "initial"});`

[pointer-events documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

---

**Edit** to adress comments about keyboard events:

`$("selector").children().prop("tabIndex",-1);` will avoid a tab navigation to access an `<input>` or `<button>`.

[tabindex documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

But since your elements are `<div>`... I don't really think that is relevant. But try it and see if that add-on code really is necessary and feel free to comment for future readers. ;)

Comment: Careful! The name may make this apparent, but this doesn't handle keyboard events

Comment: Good point... That is **pointer** (read: mouse) events disabling...

Comment: `prop('tabindex', -1)` for keyboard.

Comment: Added something about your ideas related to keyboard events. While unsure it is relevant, it is nice questionings to add to the answer. ;)