# How to make a disabled 'Apple sign-in button'?

Tags: javascript, html, apple-sign-in

I have Apple sign-in button and checkbox that the user agrees with the terms.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"></script>
<div id="appleid-signin" class="apple-sign-in text-center" data-color="black" data-border="true" data-type="sign-up"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  AppleID.auth.init({
    clientId: '<%= ENV[ APPLE_CLIENT_ID ] %>',
    scope: 'name email',
    redirectURI: '<%= callback_apple_url %>',
    state: 'state'
  });
</script>
<input class="consent-status-checkbox oauth-terms-agreement" id="consent_status" name="consent_status" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Is it possible to make the sign-in button disabled/inactive until the user checks the box?

I tried many other solutions, but they are not working with Apple button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable HTML button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript)

Comment: @leonheess no, it doesn't work with apple button

Comment: Then it's not possible

Comment: @leonheess from all that i tried, i can disable clicking only with `pointer-events: none`, but i don't need whole disable clicking, I want there to be no redirects to the Apple website, instead this i want to show message for user.