# How can I enable/disable an element's click handler with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using it in JavaScript to enable and disable a div element:

```
$("#divbutton").css("pointer-events","auto");
```

But I want a property that enables and disables the element. How can I do that?

html

```
<div class="buttonSender" id="divbutton">Invia</div>
```

Comment: CSS? Why not [use the 'disabled' attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)?

Comment: `$("#divbutton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable HTML button using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript)

Comment: @bravemaster for enable it is sufficiently write enable instead of disabled?

Comment: `$("#divbutton").removeAttr('disabled')`

Comment: @bravemaster thanks , from css isn't there any other way?

Comment: @Benson I have a div button and not a button

Comment: @bravemaster I don't see nothing effect

Comment: To confirm: you have a <div> with a click event and you want to just _style_ it disabled, or you want to actually disable it?  The advice given above is all good, but you need to elaborate a bit.  Possibly include the HTML and mention if you're using a CSS framework?

Comment: @Fewster i have put the html code, i am using css but it isn't css framework

Comment: @Fewster this  "$("#divbutton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');" it doesn't work for me , i want to have a disabled button that then i enable when is the moment, but how can I do from CSS? is there Some way?

Comment: Since it is a button you should use `<button> ... </button>` instead of a div — you can put any HTML within the button tags just as you can with a div tag, and assistive technology will recognize it as a button. If you use a div then you need to put `<div aria-role="button">` so you might as well use a `<button>` element in the first place.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with CSS. CSS is for *style*, not function.

Comment: @StephenP I have to use a div, but from you comment I don't understand how to disable it or enable it with a div?

Comment: @Barmar ok thanks anyway

Comment: You can effectively disable clicking on an element with the CSS `div#yourdiv { pointer-events: none; }` but why do you "have to" use a div? A button can do the same job as a div.

Comment: You can put `pointer-events: auto` and `pointer-events: none` in the CSS for the class.

Comment: @Barmar yes it is that i am using, but i want a way that marks strongly the disabled/enabled button

Comment: You could use a class `button-enabled`, and put the CSS on that class.

Comment: @Barmar in what sense? i don't understand.. i have to use a div in html

Comment: Then you use `$("#divbutton").addClass("button-enabled")` instead of `$("#divbutton").css("pointer-events", "auto");`

Comment: @barmar my div belongs already to a class html

Comment: An element can have multiple classes.

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't work, i don't see anything.. however i have found the css property visibility

Comment: @Barmar this is the effect that i wanted https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_disabled but i don't managing in it... with visibility it appears and diseappears simply

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNTHI598DLO8

Answer (score 1):

While I *strongly* recommend using a `<button>` instead of a `<div>`, I can think of one case where you might not be able to change the HTML markup to do that.
I start below with the case you should strive for, using a `<button>` for a button, but follow further below with how you can "disable" a div that is *acting* as a button.

---

You can make a div act like a button by adding a click handler to it, then disable it simply by adding a class with the proper CSS, mainly by disabling `pointer-events`.

Here, the `<div>` is acting as a button by using a class, and it gets disabled by adding another class, "disabled". The click handler on the div demonstrates it is clickable by using an `alert`, and you will see that it no longer reacts to clicks when the "disabled" class gets added to the div.

```js
$('#divbutton').click(function(e) {
  // This is where you would put your code that
  // does something when the div is clicked.
  alert('The Fake Button was Clicked');
});

// This is how you can disable the fake button...
$('#demo-disable').click(function(e) {
  $('#divbutton').addClass('disabled');
});
// ...and re-enable it
$('#demo-enable').click(function(e) {
  $('#divbutton').removeClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
div.buttonSender {
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  max-width: 20em;
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: black;
  background-color: peachpuff;
}

div.buttonSender.disabled {
  background-color: lightgray;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="divbutton" class="buttonSender" role="button">
    This is the div that is acting like a button.<br> Click Me
  </div>
</section>

<section class="demo-buttons">
  <button id="demo-disable">Disable</button>
  <button id="demo-enable">Enable</button>
</section>
```

I've added the `role="button"` on the div for the purposes of accessibility, but that is not all you would have to do for proper accessibility — see the "**Note:**" in the [**ARIA: button role**](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role) documentation.

You would be much better off using a `<button>` instead of a `<div>` since you are able to put any HTML in the button tag that you could put in the div.

---

The only reason (that I can think of) that you would "have to" use a div is if the HTML is written by someone else and you have no access to change it and no way to influence the author of the HTML.
In that case you also aren't able to add classes or an ID, or write any new CSS, and would have to work with what is already there.

This demo does that by modifying the CSS using jQuery's `.css()` method, disabling then restoring the `pointer-events` — note jQuery uses the camelCased property name, so it is `pointerEvents` not `pointer-events`.

```js
/*
 * This is NOT your code - this would be the click handler that already exists.
 */
$('#divbutton').click(function(e) {
  // Assume there is already a click handler, and you want to disable it.
  // This code would be the existing handler, somewhere else, not written by you.
  alert("Invia was clicked");
});


/*
 * This would be your code, and it wouldn't be packaged with the code above
 */
// This is how you can disable the fake button...
$('#demo-disable').click(function(e) {
  $('#divbutton').css('pointerEvents', 'none');
});
// ...and re-enable it
$('#demo-enable').click(function(e) {
  $('#divbutton').css('pointerEvents', 'auto');
});
```

```css
#divbutton {
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 5em;
}

#demo-controls {
  margin-top: 2em;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <p>
    This area would be part of the page that you don't control.<br>
    The div acting like a button is below, and you can't change it.
  </p>
  <div class="buttonSender" id="divbutton">Invia</div>
</section>

<section id="demo-controls">
  <p>
    This area would not be part of the HTML, over which you have no control,
    but somehow you need a way to fire your code that disables the existing div#divbutton
    <br>
    There needs to be <em>something</em> that fires your javascript;
    these buttons simulate that.
  </p>
  <button id="demo-disable">Disable</button>
  <button id="demo-enable">Enable</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `CSS` class with the value of `pointer-events` that you want like in the following example:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('divbutton').classList.toggle('disabled');
});
```

```css
#divbutton.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
  background:yellow;
}
#divbutton {
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonSender" id="divbutton">Invia</div>
<button>click me</button>
```