# Disabled a button based on a variable change

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="printable.php">
<button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Print</button>
<a>
```

```
<script> 
        if ($verifikasi = "Pending") {
            //Disable the TextBox when TextBox has value.
            btnSubmit.disabled = true;
        } else {
            //Enable the TextBox when TextBox is empty.
            btnSubmit.disabled = false;
        }
</script>
```

I'm trying to disable Print Button if the status($verifikasi) is still "Pending", but the button is still clickable.

Comment: You need to use `==` instead of `=` when comparing values

Comment: You’re also using ```disabled=“disabled”``` and ```disabled=true/false```  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014649/how-to-disable-html-button-using-javascript#3014678 And are you sure the button on click is triggered or is it the anchor?  How do you get the reference to the button? Show more code please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` instead of `=` when comparing values

So change `$verifikasi = "Pending"` to `$verifikasi == "Pending"`

---

Working demo

```js
$verifikasi = "notPending"
if ($verifikasi == "Pending") {
    //Disable the TextBox when TextBox has value.
    btnSubmit.disabled = true;
} else {
    //Enable the TextBox when TextBox is empty.
    btnSubmit.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<a href="printable.php">
<button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Print</button>
<a>
```